# Why I do get Go error "panic: strconv: illegal AppendInt/FormatInt base"

Tags: go, casting, panic, strconv

I can't figure out, why I do get this error message during run time. It triggers even with the most simple one-liner:
`strconv.FormatUint(uint64(123), 64)`

Have I understood something very wrong here? The code compiles just fine.

EDIT: Found a solution (as later pointed out by Tim Cooper). I think [the examples in the documentation](https://godoc.org/strconv#pkg-overview) are confusing:

```
s := strconv.FormatBool(true)
s := strconv.FormatFloat(3.1415, 'E', -1, 64)
s := strconv.FormatInt(-42, 16)
s := strconv.FormatUint(42, 16)
```

When you only use base 64 and 16 in the examples, it is quite easy to make the wrong conclusion. However, now that I know what was wrong, the error message makes much more sense.

Comment: In regards to your edit: no where in the docs is 64 used for a base; it is only ever used as a bit size.

Comment: If you want base64, as in the way to represent binary data in non-binary-safe environments, `encoding/base64` gives you that.

Comment: Is it bit size also for the float in the example above? I edited the question more to make it better obvious, to which part of the documentation I was refering to. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base 64 is not supported, as specified in [the documentation](https://godoc.org/strconv#FormatUint):

> ```
> func FormatUint(i uint64, base int) string
> ```
>
> FormatUint returns the string representation of i in the given base, for 2 <= base <= 36.